# SignalR on non-Azure Web Farm

Tags: scalability, signalr, web-farm

I have implemented SignalR support for web application. It works great. The problem I'm dealing now is make it work in non-Azure web farm environment. SignalR supports Windows Azure Service Bus and Redis out of the box. Also there is RabbitMQ implementation on GitHub. All these solutions implement IMessageBus interface.

Based on our current situation we can't use Redis or RabbitMQ. So I have few questions:

1) Is there any alternative solution that uses SQL Server or MSMQ?

2) Is it difficult (possible) to implement your own solution for SQL Server or MSMQ? David's post on SignalR 0.5 (http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/02/signalr-0-5.aspx) says they are going to support SQL Server QNS or Service Broker (not SQL Server DB itself) so maybe it's a wrong way at all?

3) Is there a way to work around until this support is implemented? For example, it sounds like the we need to handle state of the connections list between servers. If we know number of nodes and their IPs we can share this information between servers via Web Service calls instead. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damian Edwards appears to have just started working on the SQL scaleout implementation. You can find the details of that implementation [here on GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer) and the [issue tracking this work can be followed here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/232).

Comment: Thanks, but sounds like this work is stopped for some reason. We used Redis

Comment: It's further along than ever before in 1.0.0.0 alpha-1, the link has just changed. Will update answer now.